# Netflix videos run very hot

Tags: videos

I have a ASUS ux305f. I downloaded the Netflix app from Ubuntu.  It works fine except that my laptop gets very hot.  Netflix using Windows 10 runs cool.  Are there adjustments I can make to Linux to correct this?

Comment: How did you installed the Netflix app? From a PPA? Have you tried to watch via the Google Chrome browser? If so, did the laptop heated?